# PHPのcomposerでアップグレードする手順について

Tags: php, composer

既に古いバージョンのchrome-php/chromeがある状態で下記処理は何が異なりますか？

案A.

```
$ composer require chrome-php/chrome
```

案B.

```
$ composer update
```

案A2.

```
$ composer require chrome-php/chrome
$ composer update
```

案B2.

```
$ composer update
$ composer require chrome-php/chrome
```

---

質問背景
chrome-phpを最新の安定版にアップデートしようと思い、よく分からないまま案A2.を試しました。
コマンド自体は特にエラー表示されることもなく終了したのですが、上記それぞれ何が違うのが知りたく質問しました。

環境
CentOS7
PHP 7.4.33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

マニュアルには以下の通り記載があります。

[Command-line interface / Commands - Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md)

> #### [update / u / upgrade](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#update-u-upgrade)
>
> In order to get the latest versions of the dependencies and to update the `composer.lock` file, you should use the `update` command. This command is also aliased as `upgrade` as it does the same as `upgrade` does if you are thinking of `apt-get` or similar package managers.
>
> #### [require / r](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#require-r)
>
> The `require` command adds new packages to the `composer.json` file from the current directory. If no file exists one will be created on the fly.

日本語での解説ページもヒットします。

[composer install, update, requireの違いと使用例](https://www.geekfeed.co.jp/geekblog/composer_install_update_require/)